# Why isn't Visual Studio Code with the Arduino Extension from MS properly recognizing keywords?

Tags: arduino, visual-studio-code

Trying out the new VS Code Arduino extension.  Definitely has promise!

However, I can't seem to get it to recognize keywords.  Here's a screenshot showing the red squigglies which shouldn't be there.

[image]

So what do you have to do to get it to correctly work?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Mac and found the answer here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-arduino/issues/438

The solution was to add at the begin of the sketch:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
```

and manually add the following libraries to the c_cpp_properties.json (for the Arduino Uno):

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino",
            "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include",
            "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/include",
            "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/mega"
        ],
        "browse": {
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": false,
            "path": [
                "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino",
                "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include",
                "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/include",
                "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/mega"
                ]
        },
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
        "macFrameworkPath": [
            "/System/Library/Frameworks",
            "/Library/Frameworks"
        ]
    }
],
"version": 3
```

}

Comment: Excellent! Worked for me too!